# Is it possible to get "Active Directory" groups and members using client object model in sharepoint2013?

Tags: csom

Is it possible to get "Active Directory" groups and members using client object model in sharepoint2013?

If any one know please share your ideas. :)

Answer (score 1):

No, AD groups and members are stored in AD, so SharePoint CSOM code is unable to enumerate those.

You need to query AD for these details e.g., like described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7242226/get-members-of-active-directory-group-and-check-if-they-are-enabled-or-disabled).

Using server side, you could utilize SP API for this, like described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4314767/getting-members-of-an-ad-domain-group-using-sharepoint-api).

Comment: so, is it possible in server side  code?

Comment: Updated my answer

Comment: ok. I get user name and user id of logged user exist in AD Group..using client object model? then hw it possible?

Comment: Because SharePoint synchronizes certain user properties from AD to SharePoint User Profile Service, and you can query these user profile properties using CSOM.